# php form won't send or go to header location after submit

Tags: php, forms, submit, form-submit

I have a simple php form for contact purposes. However, it won't send the email or go to the correct page after submit. It redirects to the mail.php instead.

My contact form named contact.php is as follows:

```
 <form id="contact-form" action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset>

        <label><span class="text-form">Your Name:</span> <input type="text" name="name"></label>
        <label><span class="text-form">Your Email:</span><input type="text" name="email"></label>
        <label><span class="text-form">Your Contact No:</span><input type="text" name="contact"></label>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="text-form">Your Message:</div>
            <textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
            <div class="clear">
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
        <a class="button" href="#"><input class="button" type="submit" value="Send"></a>
        <a class="button" href="#"><input class="button" type="reset" value="Clear"></a>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And the php code named mail.php is as follows:

```
    <?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    &contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "info@whatever.co.za";
    $subject = "Contact form message";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    header("Location:contact.php");
    ?>
```

What am i doing wrong. It just wont send the message to email or redirect to the correct page??

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: space after semicolon? `"Location: contact.php"` ? Are you sure you have correct URL?

Comment: @slugonamission. No i dont get any errors only a blank page when it redirect to mail.php.

Comment: And the url is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is ever so slightly wrong. `&contact` on line 5 should be `$contact`. I assume you're on a production server, so error reporting would be disabled and you wouldn't get any warnings.

Comment: Thank you for the notice on the syntax error. Its always the smallest stupid mistakes that takes a lifetime to correct. As well as change the syntax to the correct, i added an "@" before mail, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try using @ before mail function

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "info@whatever.co.za";
$subject = "Contact form message";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
@mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header("location: contact.php");
?>
```

this will let you pass even if mail function produce any issue. Also please check if there are any other header are not sent using http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php function.

I would strongly suggest to use PHPMailer or some other class to send any kind of email.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the contact.php file whether some redirection is happening from contact.php to mail.php

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be an issue sending mail from your server. The mail.php file is probably tripping up on the mail function and not doing the redirect.

Create a new file with just the php mail function in there (with your email address and a test message) and browse it from your web browser, does it send?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ob_start() at the start of script, and exit(); after header("Location: contact.php");

smth like this ...

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    &contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "info@whatever.co.za";
    $subject = "Contact form message";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    header("Location: contact.php");
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: I have just tried that, to no avail. Shall i start pulling my hair out?? Cant be this difficult to get a simple contact form to send.

Comment: is it redirecting to contact.php ??

Answer (score 0):

Change the mail.php to the following:

```
<?php
mail("info@whatever.co.za", "Contact form message", $_POST['message'], "From: ".$_POST['name']." <".$_POST['email'].">");
header("Location: contact.php");
?>
```